# Combining the logic of two if statements

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make the following JavaScript if..else condition short, instead of writing `if() else()` function two times is there any way to write `if(x,y = ""){} else{}` or something similar to make it shorter ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#third").click(function(){
        var xxx = $("#first").val();
        var xxy = $("#second").val();

        if (xxx == "") {
            alert("good"); 
        }
        else {
            alert("bad"); 
        }

        if (xxy == "") {
            alert("good"); 
        }
        else {
            alert("bad"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `if (!xxx || !xxy) //...` ? (empty strings evaluate to false).

Comment: `if(x == '' && y == '')` ?

Comment: I suggest you to read some tutorial on basic javascript before using JQuery, considering you don't know basic operator like || (OR) and && (AND)...

Comment: If you want to make your JavaScript codes shorter but don't know how, then use the Closure Compiler by Google 
http://closure-compiler.appspot.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the "or" syntax (`||`)

```
if(xxx == '' || yyy == '')
{
    alert("good");
}
else
{
    alert("bad");
}
```

This way, if `xxx` is an empty string OR `yyy` is an empty string, it will alert "good". If neither of them are empty, it will alert "bad"

Comment: Awesome, Thankkkkkkkkkkkk Youuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Comment: @AumkarThakur Not a problem, as you are new to the site let me just remind you that if your question is answered, you should click the tick icon to the left of the answer to accept it and mark your question as resolved

Comment: @AumkarThakur Awesome, cheers. Just wanted to make sure you knew to do it for any further questions as well, that way answerers can see if a question has already been resolved or not without reading through comments. Happy coding!

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot write a condition like that, instead you can write it as

```
if(xxx == '' || yyy == '') {}
```

Or

```
if(xxx == '' && yyy == '') {}
```

Here, `||` is an OR operator and `&&` is AND operator, the difference is 1st will return true if 1 condition satisfies, 2nd one will return true if both condition satisfies.

If you are looking for a short hand syntax, you can use [ternary operator](http://davidwalsh.name/learning-ternary-operators-tips-tricks)

Comment: Well, technically yes they can write their code like that - it's perfectly valid and works. It's a question of whether or not it works for what they're trying to achieve.

Comment: @SmokeyPHP It's on the first line and for making it short, the info is on the last line :)

Comment: Ah yes, the `x,y` - my apologies, I thought you were referencing how they'd written their larger code block

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showResult = function(val) {
        alert(val ? "good" : "bad");
    };

    $("#third").click(function(){

        var xxx = $("#first").val();
        var xxy = $("#second").val();

        showResult(xxx);
        showResult(xxy);
    });
});
```

If you want just to combine, you can write even less:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#third").click(function(){
        var xxx = $("#first").val();
        var xxy = $("#second").val();

        alert((xxx || xxy) ? "good" : "bad");
    });
});
```

and if you want the shortes code, i think it could be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#third").click(function(){
        var elems = $("#first, #second").val();

        alert((elems[0] || elems[1]) ? "good" : "bad");
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lepjw/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(xxx=="" && xxy == ""){
alert('good');
}else if(xxx!="" || xxy != ""){
alert('bad');}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
xxx=="" && xxy =="" ? alert("good") : alert("bad")
```